# Fastest way to pass data to a QObject in other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, qt

I have an object that i cant controll, which is producing data in its own thread. I need to modify and analyse this data and call a function after that. The delay between receiving the data and sending it back should be minimal (not higher than 200ms). The class working with the data must be a QObject class, because it uses some kind of ruleset that the UI can change everytime.
This QObject is also living in a QThread. Right now im using QMetaObject::invokeMethod to transfer the data to my QObject, but I always read that this is a huge performance sink.

Is there any possibility to transfer the data alot faster? Its no option to work in the uncontrollable object thread directly. So I need to execute this in my thread.

Comment: As always, profile and benchmark before optimizing further. Using a signal-slot connection instead of `invokeMethod` should give sub-millisecond latency between threads. And you can always use a thread-safe/lock-free queue to ship data between threads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case every millisecond matters, so the code should be optimized as good as possible. Im sure, that the processing of the data in the ruleset will need some time, but I cant change that. So I try to optimize the remaining part. The remaining part is not that much. Its just reading some part of the data, finding the correct ruleset, process the ruleset and give the modified data back. I thought about using a wrapper class with signals and slots instead, but how is a queued connection faster? I like the idea of a queue. But is that really fast when with mutexes?

Comment: Please make sure `invokeMethod` induces a _measurable_ and _unacceptable_ bottleneck before careening off to make your code more complicated.

Comment: Sure I will test it. I just thought there is a (simple) solution, that I just dont know. I also dont like the fact, that invokeMethod uses the main thread because its just not necesary. I thought I would find a fast and easy way ti transfer the data directly from the non qt thread to my object in a QThread. But it seems like there is no such option without increasing the complexity of the project alot

Comment: invokeMethod posts a message to whichever thread owns the target object. You can [change it](https://devdocs.io/qt~5.11/qobject#moveToThread). You can also invoke a signal cross-thread (connected to a slot on the same object, which is owned by a different thread).

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod

Comment: Yes, I know the documentation of invokeMethod. What about it?

Comment: Say that invoke method posts the event to the main loop. So I thought the QEvent is generated an posted to the main eventloop (gui thread) to be then posted to the qthread eventloop or am I wrong. Because I surely use a queued connection

Comment: The event is posted directly to the thread that owns the receiver object. Why would it pass by the main thread?

Comment: As QMetaObejct::invokeMethod is static I thought it would use the main thread for that task. Because I'm quite unsure if the threadaffinity of a qobject is readable in a threadsafe way. Also the doc says: If type is Qt::QueuedConnection, a QEvent will be sent and the member is invoked as soon as the application enters the main event loop.

Comment: Which is not: Is directly postet to the object threads eventloop

Comment: "static" has *nothing* to do with the main thread. Reading the owner thread "in a threadsafe way" is *exactly* what [QMetaMethod::invoke](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp#n2255) does. The resulting event is posted [directly](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp#n2326) to the [thread's event queue](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp#n1563) The documentation wrongly assumes you're posting to an object on the main thread.

Comment: I've probably missed something but it's not clear to me why Qt is involved here at all.  If latency is that important why not have one or more dedicated producer/consumer pipelines exchanging data/tasks via threadsafe queues?

Comment: Thanks alot @Botje. Qt is involved here, because there is also a UI which uses Qt components. The class which im talking about has signal an slots to communicate with the UI. I could use queues for the communication with the non qt thread and the qthread, but I will do profiling first to see, if invoke methods costs too much time. If not, its just easier and I dont have to use mutexes and stuff and care about threadsafety

Comment: If you can, please post your timings as an answer. That way we have something to point to next time people wonder about the speed of `invokeMethod` :)